# How to list ACLs of 1st level of sub-folders for a given folder input

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

How do i list ACLs of all sub-folders for a given path. Not recursively all the way to the bottom of tree structure but just the first level of sub-folders?

I'm referring to https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/153688-how-to-get-list-of-folder-permissions but the commands hasn't given any output

Comment: [1] do you REALLY need ps2 AND ps3 AND ps4? most windows systems are at ps5.1, so those versions are very out of date. ///// [2] take a look at >>> `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Parameter depth` <<< for how to control the subdir depth.

Comment: The link you refer to shows mutilated code, where every `$_` is shown without the underscore. If you add these underscores everywhere you see the `$` followed directly by a dot and a property name, and then remove the `-Recurse` switch you'll probabbly get what you want.

Comment: @Theo It works and i'm glad about it. Thank you.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey For some reason i can't find Depth parameter but i see that option in MS documentation and several other forums but it wouldn't show up in my powershell and throws below error
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Depth'.

Comment: @Yogad - so ... what version of PoSh are you running? that parameter was added in v3 or v4 [i think].